# Oracle find conditional max

Tags: oracle, max

I am having a a result set as follows:

```
DATE_COL_1     KEY
--------------------------------
2013-12-01     1
2013-12-01     2
2013-12-01     3
2013-12-05     4
2014-01-02     5
2015-12-12     6
2013-11-05     7
```

Is it possible to use a query in Oracle DB to find the MAX(DATE_COL_1) that is smaller than or equal to the current value but not the same record so as to have the result as follows:

```
DATE_COL_1     KEY   R
------------------------------------------
2013-12-01     1     2013-12-01
2013-12-01     2     2013-12-01
2013-12-01     3     2013-12-01
2013-12-05     4     2013-12-01
2014-01-02     5     2013-12-05
2015-12-12     6     2014-01-02
2013-11-05     7     (NULL)
```

Thanks all advice

Comment: have you tried any queries yet? Try to include rownum in your statement, so you are obtaining max of the whole column except where you are at the same rownum

Comment: Research the lag() / lead() functions and then try something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple exaple with subquery

```
with s(DATE_COL_1,KEY) as (
select date'2013-12-01',     1 from dual union all 
select date'2013-12-01',     2 from dual union all 
select date'2013-12-01',     3 from dual union all 
select date'2013-12-05',     4 from dual union all 
select date'2014-01-02',     5 from dual union all 
select date'2015-12-12',     6 from dual union all 
select date'2013-11-05',     7 from dual )
select DATE_COL_1
      ,KEY
      ,(select max(DATE_COL_1) from s subs where subs.date_col_1 <= s.date_col_1 and subs.key != s.key)
  from s;
```